# Demote heading tags (convert h1 to h2, h2 to h3 recursively)in string using php

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, domdocument

I know we can get the heading by loading the string into the

`$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_str);`

And then get the H1 tags like so:

```
$list = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h1");
for ($i = 0; $i < $list->length; $i++) {
   print($list->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>\n");
}
```

If i want to change these H1s to H2s I'm a bit lost. I've read about the `appendChild()`, but that would make things very messy. Is there a way to recursively demote heading tags in a string that contains html? The method would accept the following parameters:

```
function demoteHeadings($xml_string, $top_level='H2'){
   //if string's highest heading is more than $top_level,
   //we demote all headings in this html by 1 level. i.e. if
   //h1 is found, all h1s, h2s and so on are demoted one level -
   //and we recursively    call this function again;
   if($top_level_in_xml > $top_level) demoteHeadings($output, $top_level);
}
```

I hope I make sense. What I'm trying to achieve is auto parsing the headings that my clients enter in their CMS's... They use H1's in the articles, when the title already is a h1. And sometimes, there's also a page title with is a h1, which really messes up the structure on the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be simpler to just use [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

```
$content = str_ireplace(array('<h1>','</h1>'),array('<h2>','</h2>'),$input);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes when you think too hard the solution might just be too simple to figure out. thanks!

Comment: This will not work if H tags have classes or other attributes.

Comment: @PolarTheDog Good point. Dont use regex or simple string manipulation to parse or alter HTML. Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 1):

This solution will perform a simple search and replace to demote heading tags. For example, it will change `<h1>` to `<h2>` and `<h2>` to `<h3>`, and so on.

A more robust solution would use `DOMDocument` but I couldn't find a working solution anywhere on Stack Overflow. I decided against spending time solving this problem the most precise or "right" way since this solution will probably be good enough in 99% of cases.

```php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $html = str_ireplace("<h" . $i, "<h" . $i . "_replace", $html);
    $html = str_ireplace("</h" . $i . ">", "</h" . $i . "_replace" . ">", $html);
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $html = str_ireplace("<h" . $i . "_replace", "<h" . ($i + 1), $html);
    $html = str_ireplace("</h" . $i . "_replace" . ">", "</h" . ($i + 1) . ">", $html);
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the second loop by just iterating the other direction.  `for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)...`

Answer (score 0):

Since the articles will be in deeper containers, styling them appropriately shouldn't be a problem. However I gather you've already considered that

I will get told off for suggesting regex to parse HTML ... BUT since your clients are entering HTML with a CMS, I gather the syntax of the input is very reliable and the elements have no attributes, so why not simply str_replace?

Ah, Lawrence beat me to it

Comment: Yup @lawrence-cherone beat you to it, but you're just as much appreciated. I feel like an moron. Yes. Of course str_replace will do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Another variation on the str_ireplace solution but a little bit more robust (takes in account h1 to h100)

```
function demoteHtmlHeaderTags($html)
{
        $originalHeaderTags = [];
        $demotedHeaderTags = [];

        foreach(range(100, 1) as $index)
        {
            $originalHeaderTags[] = '<h' . $index .'>';

            $originalHeaderTags[] = '</h' . $index . '>';

            $demotedHeaderTags[] = '<h' . ($index + 1) . '>';

            $demotedHeaderTags[] = '</h' . ($index + 1) . '>';
        }

        return str_ireplace($originalHeaderTags, $demotedHeaderTags, $html);
}
```

Comment: ... pretty sure [defined headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) only go up till 6?